# adicionar e remover o numero do input

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma pagina de seleção de imagem e queria q ao clicar em escolher o numero fosse para o input e se clicar novamente ele sair do input pois serao varias fts escolhidas 
corpo

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['tkm'])){
    $redirect = "index.php";
   header("location:$redirect");
}else{
    include 'conn.php';
    $tkm=$_SESSION['tkm'];
    $sql="SELECT id FROM `usuario` WHERE tkm='$tkm'";
    $executar= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $num= mysqli_num_rows($executar);
    if($num == 1){
        while($show=mysqli_fetch_array($executar)){
            $id=$show['id'];
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Selecionar Fotos</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarColor01" style="">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="sair.php">sair</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

        <?php
                    $sql="SELECT foto FROM `foto` WHERE usuario=$id";
                    $executar= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
                    //$num= mysqli_num_rows($executar);
                    $i=0;
                    while($show=mysqli_fetch_array($executar)){
                        $foto=$show['foto'];
                        $i++;
                ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">


                        <div class="select zoom">
                            <img  src="<?php echo $foto; ?>" onclick="imgZ('mostrar');AplI('<?php echo $foto; ?>');" >
                            <img class="veisto" src="visto.png" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" >
                        </div>

                        <button onclick="escolha('<?php echo $i; ?>');marcar('<?php echo $i; ?>')">escolher</button>

                    </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>  
                 <form action="" method="post">
                 <input type="text" name="escolidos" id="escolidos">
                    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
                </form>


        </div>

   </div>
   <div id="mostrar" class="mostrar">
       <img src="x.png" class="img-fechar" onclick="imgF('mostrar')" title="fechar">
       <center>
            <div id="zoomimg" class="img"></div>
        </center>
    </div>
<script src="div.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
<?php
    }else{
        $redirect = "sair.php";
        header("location:$redirect");
    }
?>

<?php
}

?>
```

javascript

```
function imgZ(el){   
   document.getElementById(el).style.display="block";
}
function AplI(el){
    document.getElementById('zoomimg').innerHTML=" <img src=\""+ el +"\" class=\" AplI \">";   
}
function imgF(el){
    document.getElementById(el).style.display="none";
}
function escolha(el){
    var visto = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    if(visto == "none")
        document.getElementById(el).style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById(el).style.display="none";
}
function marcar(el){
    var visto = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    if(visto == "none")
        document.getElementById('escolidos').value += el+"%";
    else
    document.getElementById('escolidos').value -= el;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
document.getElementById('escolidos').value -= el;
```

Aí você está fazendo uma operação matemática de subtração.

O correto seria fazer um `replace`:

```
document.getElementById('escolidos').value = document.getElementById('escolidos').value.replace(el+"%", '');
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function escolha(el){
    var visto = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    if(visto == "none")
        document.getElementById(el).style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById(el).style.display="none";
}
function marcar(el){
    var visto = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
    if(visto == "none")
        document.getElementById('escolidos').value += el+"%";
    else
    document.getElementById('escolidos').value = document.getElementById('escolidos').value.replace(el+"%", '');

}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarColor01" style="">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="sair.php">sair</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
                        <div class="select zoom">
                            <img  src="<?php echo $foto; ?>" onclick="imgZ('mostrar');AplI('<?php echo $foto; ?>');" >
                            <img class="veisto" src="visto.png" id="1" >
                        </div>

                        <button onclick="escolha('1');marcar('1')">escolher</button>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
                        <div class="select zoom">
                            <img  src="<?php echo $foto; ?>" onclick="imgZ('mostrar');AplI('<?php echo $foto; ?>');" >
                            <img class="veisto" src="visto.png" id="2" >
                        </div>

                        <button onclick="escolha('2');marcar('2')">escolher</button>

                    </div>
                 <form action="" method="post">
                 <input type="text" name="escolidos" id="escolidos">
                    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
                </form>


        </div>

   </div>
   <div id="mostrar" class="mostrar">
       <img src="x.png" class="img-fechar" onclick="imgF('mostrar')" title="fechar">
       <center>
            <div id="zoomimg" class="img"></div>
        </center>
    </div>
```